# How to make a multivalue dropdown search criteria as mandatory in RDL reports

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

I am new to RDL. In my current application we have a report (we are using the report file with .rdl extension) with lot of filtering options (from date, to date and few dropdowns).

And the dropdown is loaded with a default value as `<Select a value>`.

When I try to perform search without selecting any valid option in the dropdown, it throws a error message something like value for the dropdown field/parameter is missing.

I reviewed the query which is being used for loading the values to the dropdown and noticed that it is returning only the data. I mean the `<Select a value>` is not returning from the DB. However, it's getting displayed in the aspx page.

I also searched for the `<Select a value>` in the entire code directory, but I couldn't find any files with this text.

I am not sure, how this value is getting assigned to the dropdown.

In short, the dropdown field/paramter is marked as a mandatory parameter with a default value. But I am not sure where the default value is getting assigned to the dropdown.

Comment: Select a value... this is the default text I am seeing in the dropdown

Comment: Why was this marked as off-topic?  This is a question regarding formatting data in SSRS 2008 and reporting services which are fairly common topics for questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have have misunderstood but I think the problem is that you **have not** defined a default value.

By design, for multi-value parameters, `<select a value>` is used as a placeholder if no values have been selected by default. You will not find it on your code anywhere, it's part of the drop down control.

Here's one of my reports that shows the exact same thing.

[image]

**If you do not** require defaults the you can leave this as it is, the warning you saw is correct as nothing has been selected.

**If you do** require defaults, then you can set these in the parameter properties.

Comment: In my testing of this issue, when setting the default value from a query, datasets that only returned one value showed initially as that value.  However when the dropdown was populated with more than one value, the `<Select a Value>` option showed up,even with a default set.  I believe the issue is that he doesn't want the `<Select a Value>` to show, rather he wants the first value populated to be shown initially in preview mode, hence my answer with an additional dataset getting the first value.

Comment: I understand. I think the question is a little vague. I read it as. "the drop down has a default value of <select a value> but I can;t see where it comes from".. Only time will tell I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

To locate the parameter default setting:

left mouse click parameters from Report Data tab, right mouse click the parameter you wish to edit, select properties, select default values, you have three options: No default value, Specify values or Get values from a query.

Comment: I already reviewed that... but I don't find any configurations in that.. very curious to know is there any other place we can configure this default values for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to SuperSimmer's answer, the only way to set the default is from the Parameter Default settings.  Somewhat of a workaround for the issue you have, but it worked in my test.

What I'd recommend doing is creating a new dataset using the same query that populates the dropdown, EXCEPT you will be using `SELECT TOP 1`.  Then set the default parameter setting to `Get values from a query`, select your new dataset and the value that you need and it should work.

[image]

[image: image2]

You've probably already done this, but you also need to make sure that "Allow blank values" and "Allow null values" are unchecked.